# Scala: sort an array or set

Tags: scala, sorting, collections, quicksort

I am using the following code to sort mySet:

```
  val myArray = scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(mySet.toArray)
  var newKey = ""
  for (item <- myArray) {
     newKey += item

  }
```

However, I got the error `"value foreach is not a member of Unit"`. What does this mean and how do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scala.util.Sorting.quickSort` sorts the array in place; it returns nothing (i.e. `Unit`). To fix it, just store the array in some variable:

```
val myArray = mySet.toArray
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(myArray)
var newKey = ""
for (item <- myArray) {
   newKey += item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the `sorted` method:

```
for (item <- mySet.sorted) { ... }
```